# ubuntu 12.04 ruby 2.0 rails: Could not find 'thread_safe'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, rvm, ruby-2.0

im installing rails on ubuntu 12.04. installed manualy, using this method:
[How do I install ruby 2.0.0 correctly on Ubuntu 12.04?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16222738/how-to-install-ruby-2-0-0-correctly-on-ubuntu-12-04)

then:

```
gem update --system 
gem install rails
```

now if i run command "rails" the output is as following:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:298:in `to_specs': Could not find 'thread_safe' (~> 0.1) - did find: [thread_safe-0.1.2-java] (Gem::LoadError)
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1265:in `block in activate_dependencies'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1254:in `each'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1254:in `activate_dependencies'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1236:in `activate'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1268:in `block in activate_dependencies'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1254:in `each'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1254:in `activate_dependencies'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1236:in `activate'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:48:in `gem'
        from /usr/local/bin/rails:22:in `<main>'
```

edit:

yes i tryed:

```
gem install --version 0.1.2 thread_safe
gem uninstall thread_safe
gem install thread_safe
```

after reinstalling thread_safe rails gave me the same error

Comment: `gem install thread_safe --version 0.1.2 ` did you try this?

Comment: this seems to be the same question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18709565/why-cant-i-open-a-new-ruby-project-after-installation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you are using 2.1.0 version of rubygems. It's not bug of tread_safe or atomic gems, but it's bug of rubygems 2.1.0. Try to install older version (like 2.0.8). How to do this:

```
gem uninstall rubygems-update
gem install rubygems-update --version 2.0.8
update_rubygems
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message says thatyou don't have thread_safe version ~>0.1, and that it found thread_safe version 0.1.2-**java**,but i guess this version was not compatible/satisfactory.

probably somehow the **non-java** version was not getting installed coz of the presence of the **java** version. install the gem separately.

```
gem install --version 0.1.2 thread_safe
```

Comment: tryed this command, returned no output, gem list shows me that it is installed, but when i run rails the error pops up. tryed gem uninstall thread_safe and installing again, no luck

Answer (score 0):

so i searched for atomic gems, found atomic (1.1.14 ruby java). mine was atomic (1.1.13 java). It might be because i had no JDK 8 installed, but after installing atomic (1.1.14 ruby java) command rails gives me nice list of available parameters.

rails new test_app = success!!!