# Ubuntu 12.04 ruby 1.9.3 Rails 4.0: Could not find 'atomic'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

When I try to create a rails app "rails new project" I get the following:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:298:in `to_specs': Could not find 'atomic' (>= 0) - did find: [atomic-1.1.13-java] (Gem::LoadError)
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:1265:in `block in activate_dependencies'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:1254:in `each'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:1254:in `activate_dependencies'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:1236:in `activate'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:1268:in `block in activate_dependencies'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:1254:in `each'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:1254:in `activate_dependencies'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:1236:in `activate'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:1268:in `block in activate_dependencies'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:1254:in `each'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:1254:in `activate_dependencies'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:1236:in `activate'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:48:in `gem'
from /usr/local/bin/rails:22:in `<main>'
```

I had the previous issue that is being discussed here [ubuntu 12.04 ruby 2.0 rails: Could not find 'thread_safe'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18713406/ubuntu-12-04-ruby-2-0-rails-could-not-find-thread-safe).

After installing the thread-safe gem, the error went away and then came up with the `Could not find 'atomic' error.` I tried:

```
gem install atomic
```

with various versions, but I am still getting this error. I noticed these issues have been appearing with other users today.

Comment: What does "gem install atomic" return as output? (without specifying a version)

Comment: i have the same problem and for me "gem install atomic" returns this:


    Fetching: atomic-1.1.13-java.gem (100%)
    Successfully installed atomic-1.1.13-java
    Parsing documentation for atomic-1.1.13-java
    Installing ri documentation for atomic-1.1.13-java
    Done installing documentation for atomic after 0 seconds
    1 gem installed

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact issue right now on OSX 10.8.4

Do you have to use 1.9.3?  I just switched to 2.0.0 and reinstalled rails and it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have rubygems 2.1.0 installed? Might be a rubygems 2.1.0 bug

Try this:
sudo gem update --system 2.0.8

Then run the rails install again (after having uninstalled the -java gems of course)